# Facebook SDK , can`t import facebook libraries classes

Tags: java, android, facebook

I`ve followed the FB SDK developer guide. Get my keyhash and added the com_facebook_android as librarie reference in my project.

The thing is In my projet I can`t import the com_facebook_android classes.

```
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook; // error here "The import com.facebook.android.Facebook cannot be resolved"


public class WisePalantir extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID"); // therefore error here since I cant import Facebook class
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry I`m a newbie, which is obvious by now.